# Safari small pop-up windows do not disappear

Tags: safari, popupwindow, macos-big-sur

I am using safari 14.1.1 on Big Sur 11.4. If I go to a page on stack overflow several small windows appear with text like "Show activity on this post". They are all over the page blocking the view of the content on the page. They do not go away. If I click on them nothing happens. Any suggestions how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem is caused by the ReadCube Papers Safari extension. When I switch off the extension, the problem disappears.